# Mongoid association extension proxy owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm struggling how to get to an extended association owner in Mongoid. AFAIK it's proxy_association.owner in ActiveRecords.

```
class Something
  field :some_field

  has_many :whatevers, extend: ExtraStuff
end

module ExtraStuff
  def recent
    # I need "some_field" here, but there's no "proxy_association"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 'base' is the method you are looking for!

```
class Something
  field :some_field

  has_many :whatevers, do
      def my_extension_method
        klass # Something
        base  # #<Something _id="..." >
      end
  end
end
```

Just for reference: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3171